# Debugging: SQL inside Python Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, debugging, psycopg2, string-literals

```
sql = "WITH users AS(SELECT * FROM stats.core_users cu LEFT JOIN XXXX.sent_hidden_users h USING(user_id)\
    WHERE cu.status = 'hidden' AND h.user_id is null AND cu.country_code = 86 LIMIT 100)\
SELECT\
    cu.user_id,\
    CASE WHEN cu.gender = 'male' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS gender,\
    CASE WHEN cu.looking_for_gender = cu.gender THEN 2 WHEN cu.looking_for_gender = 'both' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS sexual_orientation,\
    CASE WHEN e2.os_name = 'iOS' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS device,\
    ROUND((DATE(NOW()) - cu.birthdate)/365.25) AS user_age,\
    SUM(dsb.likes) AS likes,\
    SUM(dsb.dislikes) AS dislikes,\
    SUM(dsb.blocks) AS blocks,\
    SUM(dsb.matches) AS matches,\ 
    SUM(dsb.received_likes) AS received_likes,\
    SUM(dsb.received_dislikes) AS received_dislikes,\
    SUM(dsb.received_blocks) AS received_blocks,\
    cu.search_radius,\
    cu.search_min_age,\
    cu.search_max_age,\
    '' AS recall_case,\
    '' AS recall_retention\
FROM \
    users cu\
LEFT JOIN \
    yay.daily_swipes_by_users dsb ON (dsb.user_id = cu.user_id) \
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (\
    SELECT \
            cd.os_name \
    FROM \
            stats.core_devices cd \
    WHERE \
            cu.user_id = cd.user_id \
    ORDER BY cd.updated_time DESC LIMIT 1) e2 ON TRUE \
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,13,14,15,16,17\
;"
```

### Error Information:

File "", line 5
    sql = "WITH users AS(SELECT * FROM stats.core_users cu LEFT JOIN zhangqiao.sent_hidden_users h USING(user_id)        WHERE cu.status = 'hidden' AND h.user_id is null AND cu.country_code = 86 LIMIT 100)SELECT        cu.user_id,        CASE WHEN cu.gender = 'male' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS gender,        CASE WHEN cu.looking_for_gender = cu.gender THEN 2 WHEN cu.looking_for_gender = 'both' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS sexual_orientation,        CASE WHEN e2.os_name = 'iOS' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS device,        ROUND((DATE(NOW()) - cu.birthdate)/365.25) AS user_age,        SUM(dsb.likes) AS likes,        SUM(dsb.dislikes) AS dislikes,        SUM(dsb.blocks) AS blocks,        SUM(dsb.matches) AS matches,\
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ^

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "users"
LINE 1: ...l_case,        '' AS recall_retentionFROM         users cuLE...               --------------- Is this because of [Psycopg2 With Statement](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a space after the `\` in `SUM(dsb.matches) AS matches,\`.  Get rid of that. As currently written, you are escaping the space with `\` rather than the newline.

Your second error is because you need a space *before* the `\` in this line:

```
'' AS recall_retention\
```

Because when you write:

```
    '' AS recall_retention\
FROM \
    users cu\
```

You get as a result:

```
'' AS recall_retentionFROM users cu
```

Hopefully the error there is obvious.  Rather than mucking around with all these escapes, maybe you should just simplify your code by using multiline quotations (either `'''` or `"""`), like this:

```
sql = """WITH users AS(SELECT * FROM stats.core_users cu LEFT JOIN XXXX.sent_hidden_users h USING(user_id)
    WHERE cu.status = 'hidden' AND h.user_id is null AND cu.country_code = 86 LIMIT 100)
SELECT
    cu.user_id,
    CASE WHEN cu.gender = 'male' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS gender,
    CASE WHEN cu.looking_for_gender = cu.gender THEN 2 WHEN cu.looking_for_gender = 'both' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS sexual_orientation,
    CASE WHEN e2.os_name = 'iOS' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS device,
    ROUND((DATE(NOW()) - cu.birthdate)/365.25) AS user_age,
    SUM(dsb.likes) AS likes,
    SUM(dsb.dislikes) AS dislikes,
    SUM(dsb.blocks) AS blocks,
    SUM(dsb.matches) AS matches,
    SUM(dsb.received_likes) AS received_likes,
    SUM(dsb.received_dislikes) AS received_dislikes,
    SUM(dsb.received_blocks) AS received_blocks,
    cu.search_radius,
    cu.search_min_age,
    cu.search_max_age,
    '' AS recall_case,
    '' AS recall_retention
FROM
    users cu
LEFT JOIN
    yay.daily_swipes_by_users dsb ON (dsb.user_id = cu.user_id)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
            cd.os_name
    FROM
            stats.core_devices cd
    WHERE
            cu.user_id = cd.user_id
    ORDER BY cd.updated_time DESC LIMIT 1) e2 ON TRUE
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,13,14,15,16,17
;"""
```

Comment: ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "users"
LINE 1: ...l_case,        '' AS recall_retentionFROM         users cuLE...               --------------- Is this because of [Psycopg2 With Statement](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement)